# react: export {ModuleName} was not found (module has no exports)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

React CRA sometimes can not find react tsx modules.
React version: 18.2.0
Node version: 19.2.0

I've tried to lower Node version. I've tried change export from `export * from './ModuleName` to `export {ModuleName} from './ModuleName` and change import from something like `import {ModuleName} from ./ModuleName` to `import {ModuleName} from ./ModuleName/ModuleName`. Sometime it helps, sometimes not.

All components written in next pattern:

```
type ModuleNameProps = {/* some props *.};

export const ModuleName = ({/* props */}: ModuleNameProps): JSX.Element => { /* Component body */};
```

```
export * from './ModuleName';
```

P.S. Application still works with such errors and other developers on a project don't have such errors

P.P.S. Such errors seem to occur only when path to component contains repetitions. For example: './ComponentName/ComponentName/ComponentName.tsx'

Comment: You are exporting `Comp`, so I think it has to be `import {Comp} from ./ModuleName/ModuleName`

Comment: Can you provide the component code how you are exporting it in the file and then the code from which your are calling the import of this file

Comment: @MoritzRingler 'ModuleName' here was just placeholder. I've changed code to eliminate misunderstanding.

Comment: @devin, unfortunately I can not provide the full code. Example of import I've provided in the question: `import {ModuleName} from {{PathToModuleClosestExport}}`. Sometimes specifying more concrete (deeper) path to component helps.

Comment: pecifying more concrete (deeper) path to component helps DO NOT DO THAT

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was working fine before.

I just imported the component directly from the file.

Comment: what do you mean ? please explain how your answer can solve the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).